# Is there a good review on complete class theorems?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, references, estimators, decision-theory

I'm trying to get an overview of the various results called "complete class theorems" and their relatives, especially the ones that say things along the lines of "every admissible decision rule is a (limit of generalised) Bayes rule(s)". This is hard because there are papers from the 1940s into the 2020s, all proving subtly different results, some of which are generalisations of previous results while others stand alone.

However, so far I haven't been able to find a single review paper on the topic. So I'm looking for something - whether it's a stand-alone review paper, a research paper that happens to have a good review section, or a textbook - that tries to give an overview of these results and how they fit together.

My interest is not so much in examples or practical applications as in theorems - my main objective is to understand exactly what's known in this space and what isn't. To a lesser extent I'm also interested in a historical perspective - who proved the main results, and which ones were generalisations of previous results?

My ideal resource would have the theorem-proof style of exposition, and would start by proving the most general results before going into special cases. Does anything like this exist?

**Edit:** I should add that I'm ideally looking for something relatively short and self-contained - an overview of the important results rather than a comprehensive treatment. Individual research papers tend not to be very helpful because the custom in this field is not to include a literature review, so it's very difficult to get an idea of how the results relate to one another. (But if there is a relatively recent paper that *does* include a literature review it would make a great answer.) The textbook recommendation in the comments are very helpful, but the ideal thing would be one where the results on this topic are given in a single self-contained chapter.

Comment: Ferguson in his intermediate treatise on decision theory has a rather nice discussion on complete class theorems (don't have the book now, but possibly second or third chapter). Then Wald, AFAIR, also had a rudimentary discussion on complete class strategies.

Comment: @User1865345 thanks, that's helpful. Do you mean [Fergusson (1967) Mathematical Statistics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781483182537/mathematical-statistics)? Being from 1967 I imagine it misses out on a lot of recent results though - it seems like Brown's results from the 70s and 80s are generally considered important.

Comment: Exactly. I don't think Ferguson's book was revised anytime later. More importantly, it was an intermediate intro and not an advanced course. But at least, it did cover the topic.

Comment: I haven't gone through the book completely, but I would suggest to check Strasser's book on Statistical Experiments.

Comment: @N.Virgo: Indeed, Larry's papers cover a lot of ground on complete class and admissibility results. His 1986 [Fundamentals of Exponential Families](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4355554) has some sections on completeness as well.